# How to enable vertical scroll in a horizontal swiper (idangero swiper )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, swiper.js

I create a swiper([idangero swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper)) whose direction is horizontal, but the content height in each slide is overed one screen.

Then the bottom part of content can't display always, bacause the horizontal swiper don't support vertical scroll.

Who can help me ?
Thanks very much.

Comment: mind to share us the code of what you did ?

Comment: From Review: Could you please provide Code to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have soved the issue by adding overflow style settings to the ks-swiper-slide element.

```
 <ks-swiper-slide  style="overflow:auto;"  ...>
```